# Simple CSS menu that can float over arbitary succeeding content

Tags: html, css, menu, hover, css-float

I want a nice clean solution that only uses CSS, no JavaScript.
I am most interested if/how this requires `z-index` settings on the `<menu>` and on other elements and if there is clean solution that does not require `z-index` settings, esp. not on the "content" tags. And of course, the content following the menu should not change positions when the menu is open.

Desired (exemplary) html structure:

```
<menu>
  <ul>
    <li>Item 1
    <li>Item 2
    <li>BigItm3
    <li>Item 4
    <li>Item 5
    <li>LastItm
  </ul>
</menu>
<p>Text</p>
<p>MoreText</p>
<p style="float:left">Floating</p>
<img style="position:absolute; left:100px; top: 40px;"
     src="http://tinyurl.com/jaheira-dance">
<form><button>OK</button><br><textarea>text</textarea></form>
<p>HTML content (e.g., loaded + injected via ajax)</p>
<iframe>
```

Desired visual behavior: 1. when not hovering over the menu

```
  --------
  | Menu |
  --------
Lorem ipsum dolor
sit amet    ==========
===== Lorem | iframe |
|img| ipsum |        |
===== dolor ==========
```

Desired visual behavior: 2. when hovering over the menu

```
  -------------
  | Menu      |
  |           |
Lo| * Item 1  |or
si| * Item 2  |=======
==| * BigItm3 |frame |
|i| * Item 4  |      |
==| * Item 5  |=======
  | * LastItm |
  =============
```

What I already have:

```
menu:before { content: "Menu"; } /* always display the menu title */

menu {
    float:   left;
    height:  16px;
    padding: 1px;
    margin:  0px;
    font-height: 10px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    border: solid 1px gray;
}

menu>ul       { display: none; }  /* hide menu items when closed */
menu:hover>ul { display: block; } /* show items when open */

menu:hover    {
    height:   auto;  /* expand menu */
    position: fixed; /* move other elements behind menu */
}

menu + * { clear: both; } /* move following content below menu */
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be all you needed to change.

**[If your cat image doesn't need to be position absolute](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/Qye2P/1/)**

```
menu {
  position: absolute; /* Change */
  top: 0; /* Change */
  left: 20px; /* Change */
  background: #fff; /* Change (not needed but without a bg the text will show through */
  height:  16px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin:  0px;
  font-height: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
}
```

**[If it does need to be absolute then you can use an z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/Qye2P/2/)**

```
menu {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 20px;
  background: #fff;
  height:  16px;
  padding: 1px;
  margin:  0px;
  font-height: 10px;
  border: solid 1px gray;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

> I am most interested if/how this requires z-index settings on the

Well the reason it is going to require a z-index is from the image having position absolute which puts those two elements on the same level.

If you have something against `z-index` then you can allow the order the elements come into the page to decide what stacks on what. By adding the menu to the end of your HTML you will achieve the desired result without a `z-index` because it is stacking on top of the other `absolute` object.

**[Without z-index](http://jsfiddle.net/Josh_Powell/Qye2P/3/)**

Comment: Thanks, this solves the problem. Making the menu `position:absolute` also makes the whole layout more stable. My floating menu caused additional problems with the subsequent elements. And having a `z-index` only on the menu is just what i wanted. This should be robust enough to allow overlaying any page content.

Comment: If you give it a lower `z-index` or just give the page overlays a high `z-index` like 1000 or so and they should overlay any element normally. Best of luck in your design!